# How to use fgetcsv with a query?

Tags: php, sql, csv

I have a csv file that is stored in another site.
I built a simple query, i want to insert the first column and the second column to my table.

When i'm going to my php page , i can see the message "Connection succeeded", it's fine but i don't have any message such as "Insert failed" or something.

No insertion is done in my table.

```
<?php
$fin = fopen('http://diederichs.com/reseller/RZZAQZYIJxPY6JxO/supply/csv','r') or die('cant open file');
try {
    $link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=;host=localhost', '', '');
    echo 'Connection succeeded <br />' . PHP_EOL;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO supply SET COL2 = :sku, reference = :reference');
    //Only give the length parameter if you **KNOW** that no line will be longer than that
    while (($data=fgetcsv($fin,1000,","))!==FALSE) {
        if ($stmt->execute(array(':sku' => $data[1], ':reference' => $data[0]))) {
            echo 'Insert ok<br />' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $err = $stmt->errorInfo();
            echo 'Insert Failed: ' . $err[2] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
fclose($fin);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using UPDATE syntax,for INSERT is

```
INSERT INTO supply(COL2,reference) VALUES(:sku,:reference)
```